# Can plugin have two links in admin navigation?

Tags: plugin-development, navigation, admin, craft-pro

Is it possible to add another link to admin navigation? For example I have plugin clients which has it's own Button in the admin menu, in the same plugin i have newsletter so I would like to have that Newsletter in that menu as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top links in the CP header are often called *nav tabs*.

Beyond the "default" nav tab for your plugin (pointing to the plugin's [CP section](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/templates.html#giving-your-plugin-its-own-cp-section)), it's possible to declare additional tabs via the [modifyCpNav](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyCpNav) hook (added in [Craft 2.3.2640](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master-v2/CHANGELOG-v2.md#232640---2015-03-12)):

```
public function modifyCpNav(&$nav)
{
    $nav['mypluginhandle-newsletter'] = array('label' => 'Newsletter', 'url' => 'mypluginhandle/newsletter');
}
```

Of course, this will only create a tab with a link pointing to whatever you put in the `url` property. If you haven't already created the page for the newsletter, you'll need to do so by creating a [route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) to a template or controller:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'mypluginhandle/newsletter' => 'myPluginHandle/newsletter',
    );
}
```

Read more about the `registerCpRoutes` hook in the [official docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/hooks-reference.html#registercproutes).

Both the `modifyCpNav()` and `registerCpRoutes()` methods should go in your plugin's main class.

Comment: Well, you learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean have multiple tabbed content within your plugin admin area? If so yes that's possible you just need to add a tabs array in your template like so:

```
{% set tabs = {
 tab1: { label: "Tab 1"|t, url: url('plugin') },
 tab2: { label: "Tab 2"|t, url: url('plugin/tab2') },
} %}
```

Then to make a tab active in the navigation you would just add this to the relevant template:

```
{% set selectedTab = 'tab2' %}
```

If you are referring to having both `clients` and `newsletter` in the top navigation I don't think so, I think it's one section per plugin (but I could be mistaken)

**Edit**

Sorry I should have elaborated, you will also need to register additional pages in your main plugin class, like so:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
  return array(
    'pluginHandle/some-page' => 'pluginHandle/_someTemplate'
  );
}
```

[There is a bunch of info about this in the plugin docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/templates#extending-the-cp-layout)